# How do I make a link in SAPUI5 using XML view?

Tags: xml, sapui5

The title is self explanatory.

I'm developing a view in SAPUI5 using the XML view format and I don't know (and can't find information anywhere) how to make a link inside the view.

For example, given this code:

```
<ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press="handleLineItemPress">
    <cells>
        <ObjectIdentifier title="{Version}" />
        <ObjectNumber number="{Ejercicio}"/>
        <ObjectNumber number="{PlanInicial}"/>
        <ObjectNumber number="{Transferencias}"/>
        <ObjectNumber number="{PlanActual}"/>
        <ObjectNumber number="{ImporteCursado}"/>
        <ObjectNumber number="{PlanDisponible}"/>
        <Text text="{Moneda}"/>
    </cells>
</ColumnListItem>
```

I need to be able to add a link to any of the ObjectNumber.

I've looked everywhere but I'm not able to find anything.

Thanks in advance for your time,
Hoijof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
press=".onObjectNumberPress"
```

in controller:

```
onObjectNumberPress: function(e) {
   var iNumber = e.getSource().getNumber();
   //open in same window
   window.location.href = "http://google.de?q="+iNumber;
   //open in new window
   window.open("http://google.de?q="+iNumber);
}
```

not tested, but should work.

but also you can write html-code in xml-view. just add the html-namespace to document-header.

```
<core:View controllerName="my.own.controller" 
   ... 
   xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<html:a href="http://google.de?q=123">TestLink</html:a>
```

Comment: The last option works for what I want to do, Thanks!

Comment: @Manuel Richarz: in your first code sample, which number would getNumber() return, since there are 6 ObjectNumbers with a number attribute in one row?

Comment: @Manuel Richarz: second code sample does not work for me, I always get an js error in the console: "Error: Neither view name/content nor an XML node is given. One of them is required.". Am I right that you can add the html:a directly as a child elemnt of <cells> ?